# What will this do: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">?

Tags: html, meta

What will this following tag will do to my browser when a HTML page is loaded?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Your caps lock key seems to be broken

Comment: I have my latest keyboard already, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

> **Understanding legacy document modes**
>
> Use the following value to display the webpage in edge mode, which is
> the highest standards mode supported by Internet Explorer, from
> Internet Explorer 6 through IE11.
>
> `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">`
>
> Note that this is functionally equivalent to using
> the HTML5 doctype. It places Internet Explorer into the highest
> supported document mode. Edge most is most useful for regularly
> maintained websites that are routinely tested for interoperability
> between multiple browsers, including Internet Explorer.
>
> **Note**  Starting with IE11, edge mode is considered the preferred document mode. (In
> earlier versions, it was considered experimental.) To learn more, see
> Document modes are deprecated. Starting with Windows Internet Explorer
> 8, some web developers used the edge mode meta element to hide the
> Compatibility View button on the address bar. As of IE11, this is no
> longer necessary as the button has been removed from the address bar.
> Because it forces all pages to be opened in standards mode, regardless
> of the version of Internet Explorer, you might be tempted to use edge
> mode for all pages viewed with Internet Explorer. Don't do this, as
> the X-UA-Compatible header is only supported starting with Internet
> Explorer 8.
>
> **Tip**  If you want all supported versions of Internet
> Explorer to open your pages in standards mode, use the HTML5 document
> type declaration, as shown in the earlier example.

Comment: Yes it was one Google query away. One which has led me to this page. Thank you for supporting the Internet and spreading knowledge!

Comment: :) Ha ha! Exactly what I was going to say! All top links for this query point to StackOverflow currently.